# Modifing date format on wp_insert_post_data hook changes rights

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I use a plugin to create a custom post type 'Offer'. In this plugin is the class 'offer'.
In the construct method I add a filter:

```
    add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', array($this,'save_offer_meta'),'99',2);
```

which calls this method:

```
public function save_offer_meta($data, $postarr)
    {
        if ($this->slug == $data['post_type']) {
        if (isset($postarr['_cpt_start_date'])) {
            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-Y', $postarr['_cpt_start_date']);
            $right_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            update_post_meta($postarr['ID'], '_cpt_start_date', $right_date);
        }
        if (isset($postarr['_cpt_end_date'])) {
            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-m-Y', $postarr['_cpt_end_date']);
            $right_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
            update_post_meta($postarr['ID'], '_cpt_end_date', $right_date);
        }
    }
}
```

I use this to format a local date input to MySQL format. I know this isn't really necessary, because the meta_value column of the wp_postmeta has datatype LONGTEXT, but I still do want to save this date in MySQL format.

This approach does work, but the strange thing is, that when I want to create any post (default post, this custom post type or any other custom post type), I can only Submit for Review, and update existing posts, although I'am logged in as administrator. When I remove the add_filter line in the constructor the rights are back as they should be (I can create, update any posts), but of course, the date is stored in its local format.

The error_log says:

```
PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ***/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1310
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ***/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1312 
PHP Warning:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in ***/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1321
```

I guess this behavior has something to do with security, but i can't figure out how to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters should return a value.  I suspect you need to add

```
return $data;
```

at the end of your routine.